# jQuery iFrame Responsive testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am rebuilding a site and we pull in via an iframe a gallery on 1 page and this is because they have a lot of global sites so when was originally built the idea was that they could just update this one file on an external domain and it update globally which of course works as expected!

The new site I'm almost finished building now is brand new, from framework, system and totally responsive so I've had to do some code changes on this external gallery and also a little on the new site (js) to help make the iframe content responsive which is working perfectly on my browser when I resize it, use chromes debug console and set device etc.

However when I actually look on my iPhone it does not seem to work and not sure if its my phone that's just caching. How can I check if the gallery being pulling through is being responsive? If it's not, any ideas where I'm going wrong with the code changes I've put in place?

New responsive site URL in question: http://2015.ambientlounge.com/about-us/custom-branded.html

JS:

```
    /* iframe heights */
var calcHeight = function() {
    $('#iframe_resize').height($(window).height() - 170);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    calcHeight();
}); 

$(window).resize(function() {
    calcHeight();
}).load(function() {
    calcHeight();
});
```

HTML:

```
<p><iframe frameborder="0" id="iframe_resize" noresize="noresize" src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/external/custom/index.html"></iframe></p>
```

Comment: Opps did not give the URL in question: http://2015.ambientlounge.com/about-us/custom-branded.html

Comment: Why don t you try to delete your cache ? Go to history, delete cache.

Comment: cleared history, cookies etc.. on iphone but does not seem responsive.... it is though if i resize browser on laptop which is weird.

Comment: iframes are a pain in the @rse to show on iPhones (most things are actually  concerning iPhones), there's not that much to the gallery, have you tried just placing it on the page itself?